# OutOfMemoryError:Java Heap space in liquibase when running a large SQL file

Tags: java, ant, liquibase

I am using Ant task for updating database. 
The ant task is

```
<target name="updatedb">
    <updateDatabase
                    changeLogFile="${prj.db.changelog.file}"
                    driver="${prj.db.driver}"
                    url="${prj.db.url}"
                    username="${prj.db.username}"
                    password="${prj.db.password}"
                    classpathref="db.liquibase.classpath">
</updateDatabase>
</target>
```

I have a changeset that runs a SQL file as

```
<changeSet author="test" id="20150603">
  <sqlFile path="data.sql"
             stripComments="true" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

When I run my ant task, I am receiving **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**
That's because the sql file has a large size.
I want to give heap space through the ant task. What changes are required to be made? Please suggest.
I dont want to use `set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"` since this will set the heap space for the ant tasks that I have.
Is there any parameter or property for liquibase through which I can increase the heap space.

Comment: Break the changeset into multiple changesets with more sql files. Surely you can break up the sql script.

Comment: Sure I will be using that as the last resort. Is there a way to do that through Ant?

Comment: Do you want to set java opts for a single ant task, but use default java opts for all other tasks? This is not possible at first, if tasks run sequentially, and I dont understand why you need this. Please clarify the situation.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker:  I can not run java_opts on servers where I will be using liquibase .For other ant tasks, to increase heap space, I use something like 
`code`<java classname="Test" fork="true">
<jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m" />
</java>. But can I use something similar for liquibase. What should be the classname in that case?

Comment: facing the same issue today in sqlcl22.4.0/liquibase4.17.0